# Axios wrapper is throwing 200 successful responses in catch block instead of then

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm writing a wrapper for Axios like below

```
// 1st approach
export const makeRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: config.baseURL
})

// 2nd approach
export const makeRequest = (options) => {
    return axios({
         ...options,
        url: config.baseURL + options.url
    })
}
```

It's working fine but the only problem is I'm getting successful 200 responses in catch block instead of then.
Any idea what could be the reason?

Sample request

```
makeRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: `url`
}).then(res=>{
  // response should be here
  console.log(res);
}).catch(err=>{
  // getting successful 200 response here
  console.log("err",err);
})
```

Comment: what catch block?

Comment: Probably need code to understand better but a guess could be the response data is not what you expect.

Comment: I would make sure the response type you are getting back is JSON. e.g. status might be 200 but the response it HTML or text. If you're calling your own API ensure you have defined your content type as json in the server endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You give the `url` property to `axios` *twice*, once explicitly named and once as part of `...options`. And the one from `...options` survives, as demonstrated by the following snippet:

```js
var options = {
  method: "GET",
  url: "relative/url"
};
console.log({
  url: "http://server/baseURL/" + options.url,
  ...options
});
```

This leads to an `axios` call without the `config.baseURL`, and that could be why it fails. If you exchange the two rows:

```js
{
  ...options,
  url: "http://server/baseURL/" + options.url
}
```

the explicit `url` will survive.

Comment: Still not fixed

Comment: it can be an issue with the 1st approach but what's wrong with 1st approach?